# How to center string in strings.xml?

Tags: xml, string, android-studio

I have a text string I would like to center in my app. This is how `strings.xml` looks like:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name"><font size="28" fgcolor='#444444'><b>Test</b></font></string>
</resources>
```

How can I center this text? Currently it is **left-aligned** in the **app's header**.

This is where the string is being used (in `AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Blue">
```

I tried `android:gravity="center"` but that does only seem to apply to TextViews... This is not a TextView, this is the header bar of the app.

Comment: Why can't you add alignment in layout file?

Comment: Which layout file? I am dealing with the headers text here and not some TextView in an Activity file...